# How to pass git ssh credentials from wsl to VScode dev-container

Tags: git, ssh, wsl-2, vscode-devcontainer

I've setup ssh keys for my gitlab account using ssh keys in WSL.

Now I want to use the same ssh git credentials in VScode dev-containers.

How do I pass ssh keys to the dev container?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In Vscode dev-container [documentation](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/devcontainers/containers#_using-ssh-keys) they explain how to use SSH agent to pass the shh keys to the container:

first find they keys files that you have on your system. To do that run the following in your WSL terminal (e.g. Ubuntu) `ls ~/.ssh/`. By default the shh key file name start with a `id_`. look for such a file (e.g. id_ed25519).

In the terminal run `eval "$(ssh-agent -s)"`. Then run `ssh-add ~/.ssh/id_ed25519` (replace the file name with your key file).

BTW to list the already added keys, run `ssh-add -l`

The problem is that in linux the ssh-agent doesn't start automatically on start up. So we need to add it to `~/.bash_profile` file.

In the terminal run `code ~/.bash_profile` to open the file in vscode. Then add the following to the file:

```bash
if [ -z "$SSH_AUTH_SOCK" ]; then
   # Check for a currently running instance of the agent
   RUNNING_AGENT="`ps -ax | grep 'ssh-agent -s' | grep -v grep | wc -l | tr -d '[:space:]'`"
   if [ "$RUNNING_AGENT" = "0" ]; then
        # Launch a new instance of the agent
        ssh-agent -s &> $HOME/.ssh/ssh-agent
   fi
   eval `cat $HOME/.ssh/ssh-agent`
   ssh-add ~/.ssh/id_ed25519
fi
```

Notice the ssh-add line at the end. This is because the ssh-agent in linux doesn't persist the keys as it does in windows.

Restart your computer or just restart WSL by running `wsl --shutdown`. This will prompt a message from docker for windows to restart. Open a new WSL terminal  as type `shh-add -l` to see that the key is there.

Now start a project in a VScode dev container and in the terminal type `shh-add -l`. The same key as in you WSL should be listed.

Comment: What if I am on a shared linux server from which I am launching the container? I can't "shutdown" the server in order to prompt the ~/.bash_profile to run. Is that a necessary or simply a verification step?

Comment: Maybe this is dependent on how you start VS Code / VS Code Dev Containers, but in my case I had to use the Windows ssh-agent. So I did set it up as described [here](https://code.visualstudio.com/remote/advancedcontainers/sharing-git-credentials) and added my ssh keys to it as described above. Those keys are now availble in the Dev Container.